# how to deal with missings when importing csv to postgres?

Tags: postgresql, csv

I would like to import a csv file, which has multiple occurrences of missing values. I recoded them into NULL and tried to import the file as. I suppose that my attributes which include the NULLS are character values. However transforming them to numeric is bit complicated. Therefore I would like to import all of my table as:

```
\copy player_allstar FROM '/Users/Desktop/Rdaten/Data/player_allstar.csv'  DELIMITER ';' CSV WITH NULL AS 'NULL' ';'  HEADER
```

There must be a syntax error. But I tried different combinations and always get:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "WITH NULL"
LINE 1: COPY  player_allstar FROM STDIN DELIMITER ';' CSV WITH NULL ...
```

I also tried:

```
\copy player_allstar FROM '/Users/Desktop/Rdaten/Data/player_allstar.csv' WITH(FORMAT CSV, DELIMITER ';', NULL  'NULL', HEADER);
```

and get:

```
 ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "NULL"
 CONTEXT:  COPY player_allstar, line 2, column dreb: "NULL"
```

I suppose it is caused by preprocessing with R. The Table came with NAs so I change them to:

```
  data[data==NA] <- "NULL"
```

I`m not aware of a different way chaning to NULL. I think this causes strings. Is there a different way to preprocess and keep the NAs(as NULLS in postgres of course)?

Sample:

```
              pts   dreb    oreb    reb asts    stl
              11    NULL    NULL     8   3      NULL
               4     5       3       8   2        1
               3    NULL    NULL     1   1      NULL
```

data type is integer

Comment: I think your second attempt is very close, but you need `FORMAT CSV` rather than just `CSV`. Not adding as answer because I'm saying that from memory...

Comment: thank you. i adjusted i but still get the error: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "NULL"
CONTEXT:  COPY player_allstar, line 2, column dreb: "NULL"

Comment: With the default settings, a NULL is written as an unquoted empty string. Is it possible to record your nulls values using empty strings ? If not, can you please give us a sample of your csv file?

Comment: Please show an example line of the input.

Comment: Thk for your comments. I add some information above.

Comment: @HiThere That's clearly not a sample of the input data, as your `\copy` uses `SEPARATOR ';'` . However, after correcting for that, it works, per my answer. You'll have to show the *actual input data with the problem* - from the CSV.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given `/tmp/sample.csv`:

```
pts;dreb;oreb;reb;asts;stl
11;NULL;NULL;8;3;NULL
4;5;3;8;2;1
3;NULL;NULL;1;1;NULL
```

then with a table like:

```
CREATE TABLE player_allstar (pts integer, dreb integer, oreb integer, reb integer, asts integer, stl integer);
```

it works for me:

```
\copy player_allstar FROM '/tmp/sample.csv' WITH (FORMAT CSV, DELIMITER ';', NULL 'NULL', HEADER);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is fine, the problem seem to be in the formatting of your data. Using your syntax I was able to load data with NULLs successfully:

```
mydb=# create table test(a int, b text);
CREATE TABLE
mydb=# \copy test from stdin WITH(FORMAT CSV, DELIMITER ';', NULL  'NULL', HEADER);
Enter data to be copied followed by a newline.
End with a backslash and a period on a line by itself.
>> col a header;col b header
>> 1;one
>> NULL;NULL
>> 3;NULL
>> NULL;four
>> \.
mydb=# select * from test;
 a |  b
---+------
 1 | one
   |
 3 |
   | four
(4 rows)

mydb=# select * from test where a is null;
 a |  b
---+------
   |
   | four
(2 rows)
```

In your case you can substitute to NULL 'NA' in the copy command, if the original value is 'NA'.

You should make sure that there's no spaces around your data values. For example, if your NULL is represented as NA in your data and fields are delimited with semicolon:

```
1;NA <-- good
1 ; NA <-- bad
1<tab>NA <-- bad
```

etc.